# Create a rule for counting the number of modules

Tags: prolog

```
student(ram,cse).
student(kirat,com).
student(ajay,cse).
student(amit,cmt).

studies(cmt,uc).
studies(cmt,pm).
studies(com,pm).
studies(com,aplc).
studies(com,ads).
studies(cse,aplc).
studies(cse,pm).
studies(cse,algorithms).
studies(cmt,pm).

classmate(X,Y):-student(X,Y).
```

I need to create the rule for "To count number of modules in all i.e. cse, cmt and com."

When I just give `cse` , `cmt` or `com` then it will show how many number of modules are there. These modules are stored in the given facts of studies how would i make a rule for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aggregate_all(count, studies(cse,_), Count).`

```
4 ?- aggregate_all(count, studies(cse,_), Count).
Count = 3.
```

It works the same with cmt, com.

As @mbratch said, this will not show the count of the *unique* modules, but the total count of them.

Comment: This counts how many times the one module `cse` is used. I think @user2334012 wants to know how many unique modules exist. So it might need to be `setof(M, studies(M, _), ListOfModules), length(ListOfModules, Num).` and `Num` will be the number of unique modules.

Comment: It might. I'm not sure what he is trying to say with ' show how many number of modules are there' exactly

Comment: Thanks @Shevliaskovic Thank u vry much. It works. But i wanted to ask you i am all new to this that the solution you have provided is this a query or a Rule

Comment: The thing is I wanted to show how many modules i.e. pm,aplc,algorithm are there in the selected branch i.e. com,cse,cmt.

Comment: what is the query for the "branches which studies both PM and APLC" .

Comment: `1?- studies(X,pm),studies(X,aplc).
X = com ;
X = cse ;`

Answer (score 2):

Two issues in the solutions pointed by Shevliaskovic and mbratch. In the first case, `aggregate_all /3` is not a standard predicate, making that solution less portable. But using `setof/3` in the way shown will not give the expected results due to the anonymous variable:

```
?- setof(M, studies(M, _), ListOfModules), length(ListOfModules, Num).
ListOfModules = [com],
Num = 1 ;
ListOfModules = [cse],
Num = 1 ;
ListOfModules = [com, cse],
Num = 2 ;
ListOfModules = [cmt, com, cse],
Num = 3 ;
ListOfModules = [cmt],
Num = 1.
```

To make the problem more clear, we can replace the anonymous variable by a named variable:

```
?- setof(M, studies(M, A), ListOfModules), length(ListOfModules, Num).
A = ads,
ListOfModules = [com],
Num = 1 ;
A = algorithms,
ListOfModules = [cse],
Num = 1 ;
A = aplc,
ListOfModules = [com, cse],
Num = 2 ;
A = pm,
ListOfModules = [cmt, com, cse],
Num = 3 ;
A = uc,
ListOfModules = [cmt],
Num = 1.
```

Correcting this issue is easy. The solution is to explicitly qualify the second argument of `studies/2` so that we don't get a solution for each value of the second argument:

```
?- setof(M, A^studies(M, A), ListOfModules), length(ListOfModules, Num).
ListOfModules = [cmt, com, cse],
Num = 3.
```